# Modeling random slopes

Tags: r, stan

I have to write down three models which try to explain frequency of voice by different factors. First two were no problem, but do not really know what they are asking for in the third model. I understand the random intercepts, but not the random slopes here. Especially since we shall use random slopes for 'attitude' twice? 
Any help appreciated.

The first one, `model_FE`, only has fixed effects. It tries to explain `frequency` in terms of `gender`, `attitude` and their interaction.

The second one, `model_intercept_only`, is like `model_FE` but also adds random intercepts for both `scenario` and `subject`.

Finally, `model_max_RE` is like `model_FE` but also specifies the following random effects structure: by-scenario random intercepts, and random slopes for `gender`, `attitude` and their interaction, as well as by-subject random intercepts and random slopes for `attitude`.

Remember to set `eval = TRUE`.

```
model_FE <- brm(formula = frequency ~ gender * attitude, 
               data = politeness_data)

model_intercept_only <- brm(formula = frequency ~ gender * attitude + (1|subject) + (1|scenario) , data = politeness_data)
```

Comment: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification

Comment: model_max_RE <- brm(formula = frequency  ~ gender * attitude + (1|scenario) + (1+gender|attitude) * (1+attitude|gender) + (1|subject) + (1+subject+gender+scenario|attitude)  ,  data = politeness_data)

Comment: Does this seem valid to you?

Comment: I just do not get why we have to add random slopes for attitude twice :( Sorry, I also Kind of lack the theoretical Knowledge, but tried to read something about it.

Comment: could someone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

The random-effects term described by

> by-scenario random intercepts, and random slopes for gender, attitude and their interaction

corresponds to

```
(1 + gender*attitude | scenario)
```

the one described by

> as well as by-subject random intercepts and random slopes for attitude.

corresponds to

```
(1 + attitude | subject)
```

These terms should be combined with the fixed effects:

```
~ gender*attitude + (1 + gender*attitude | scenario) +
   (1 + attitude | subject)
```

- In the random-effects term `(f|g)`, `g` specifies the **grouping variable**: this is always a categorical variable, and to be sensible should be an **exchangeable** variable (i.e., changing the labels on the variable shouldn't change their meaning: I would say that `sex` would *not* normally be considered exchangeable).
- The formula component to the left of the |, `f`, specifies the **terms that vary across levels of the grouping variable**: unless explicitly suppressed with `-1` or `0`, this always includes an intercept.  Unless you want to enforce that particular combinations of random effects are independent of each other, you should include all of the varying terms in the same `f` specification. You need to be especially careful if you want multiple independent `f` terms that contain categorical variables (this needs a longer explanation/separate question).
- you can sensibly have multiple "random intercepts" in the same model if they pertain to different grouping variables: e.g. `(1|subject) + (1|scenario)` means that there is variation in the intercept across subjects and across scenarios.